# Delete line in File using AutoIT

Tags: file, line, autoit

I am using AutoIt to write a text file. The only problem I am having is that it adds an extra line at the end (there is absolutely nothing on it). I would like to remove the line.. Either by never adding it or deleting it after writing everything that I need.

Example:

```
_FileCreate($file)
FileOpen($file, 0)
FileWriteLine($file,$line)
FileClose($file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `FileWrite($file, $line)` instead of `FileWriteLine($file, $line)` as the latter will always make sure, that the line ends with a carriage return (`@CR`) or a line feed (`@LF`), else a DOS linefeed (`@CRLF`) will be added as you can read in its [documentation](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileWriteLine.htm).

If you want to write multiple lines into the file with only carriage returns in between the lines, you'd either have to manually always check whether a further line will follow and only then write an extra carriage return to the file. Or you could write each line to a single array entry and in the end join them all together with `_ArrayToString($lines, @CR)`. You'd have to `#include <Array.au3>` before to be able to use this function...